# Getting elements with XPATH

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I've faced a problem, I'm trying to manually get XPath of the objects, but many elements have the same classes and I can't get only with classes, also I want to make it dynamically, so I don't want to use selector using nodes.

Well, this is how I select the object that I want to get. I want to get only the first element, how can I make that? Inside of this div is just a text.

[image]

Comment: Please add the full HTML content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements have `xpath` [attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) so you should be able to get the first element as simple as:

```
//div[@xpath='1']
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)